# Acunetix DNS lookup failed when scan websites from IIS

Tags: iis, localhost

Acunetix scanner works well for remote sites. But when I try to crawl any of my sites on this computer from IIS I get an error:

> DNS lookup failed.

example:

[image: IIS]

[image: Chrome]

[image: Acunetix admin UI]

At the same time, the site is working and I have access to it from the browser. What to do about this problem?

Comment: Why can't you just use localhost?  That way you can skip the DNS lookup (or at least, it knows to go for 127.0.0.1 instead of trying to look up ```mywebsite.localhost```  Anyway, Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  This isn't a programming question.

Comment: A simple localhost (no port or subdomain) is occupied by another site.  Besides. Even if I release a simple localhost, then this site has a second backend to which it still cannot reach (if the same error remains) (on IIS with another port).

Comment: First please make sure windows firewall isn't blocking this request, and you can also use `nslookup mywebsite.localhost:82/login` to resolve the DNS server you are currently requesting.

Comment: @samwu, hello, firewall is disabled. Your command throws an error: *** UnKnown can't find mywebsite.localhost:82/login: Non-existent domain

Comment: Do you also get this error when using other browsers? can you post the configuration of your website? Try use `ipconfig /flushdns` to clear DNS cache on your computer To fix DNS lookup failed error.

Comment: @samwu, the website works flawlessly in all browsers. i tried your cache clear command, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.